# AJAX Retrieve Value With SerializeArray - [Laravel]

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am doing a form submit and would like to pass in the form information into the controller, although I just cant access any information within the controller when I do a `serializeArray`.

```
<form class="#" action="#" method="post" id="addLink">
    <input class="form-control full-width" type="text" name="link"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>


$('#addLink').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ser = $(this).serializeArray();
    var csrf = "{{ csrf_token() }}"

    $.ajax({
        url: '/profile/addlink',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf,
        },
        data: {
            "_token": csrf,
            data : ser
        },
        success: function(data) {
         console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(data){
         console.log('error');
        },
    });

});
```

Controller

```
public function addLink(Request $request)
{
    $result = json_encode($request->data, true);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Result:

```
[{"name":"link","value":"http:\/\/test.com"}]
```

I would like to extract the 'link'

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `json_decode()` to extract the values and while sending data, you should use `JSON.stringify()`. So code should be:

JS code:

```
data: JSON.stringify(ser);
```

PHP code:

```
$result = json_decode($request->data, true);
print_r($result); // array of values
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => link
            [value] => dasd
        )

)

Comment: How can I get it to be array('link'=>'http/daks')

Comment: You can use `$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);` followed by `print_r($flat);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) over [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) in your JS

```
var ser = $(this).serialize();
```

resulting to send out the data in the format of

```
link=value
```

and in your Controller, you could extract the `link` using [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
parse_str($request->data, $output);
echo $output['link']; // Here you could get the link's value
```